# Render only the next unfilled form component in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am having a hard time with a complex form.  There are about 400 questions, most of them radio selections.  I think this is where to go with `useMemo`, or `createRef`, `useRef` or something, so that only that first blank component gets the `true` result for the styling to display.

Please help me.

Here's a basic likeness to the source

```
const SeveralForms = () => {
  return(
    // hope pseudo code is ok
    // like 10 of these
    <Form>
  )
}

const Form = () => {
  return(
    // about 30 of these
    <RadioGroup>
  )
}

const RadioGroup = () => {

  const show = () => (pesky logic i cant pin down)

  return(
    <div style={{display: show() ? 'block' : 'none' }}>
      <RadioButton />
      <RadioButton />
      <RadioButton />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: So you want to display only questions which aren't answered?

Comment: yes, but only one at a time, the first one that is not answered, thanks

Comment: Within the radiogroup class you have different set of questions and if the first one is not answered you want to show that entire group?

Comment: each `<RadioGroup>` is only 1 question, and any selection is a response, then i want the subsequent group to show, and only 1 at a time, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply:

```js
const RadioGroup = () => {
  const [isAnswered, setIsAnswered] = useState(false);

  const onClick = () => {
     // check if either of your radio buttons are checked
     // and set the state accordingly
     setIsAnswered(true /*or false*/)
  }

  return(
    <div style={{display: isAnswered ? 'none' : 'block' }} onClick={onClick}>
      <RadioButton />
      <RadioButton />
      <RadioButton />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to mark the *unanswered* questions so that only the first of them shows. I may have to set a counter up in the top level. Thank you, though. And wow, I hardly ever get an upvote. Maybe it's the easty reading pseudocode. :)